calling axios multiple times
I am trying to make a fetch function where upon fetching the transaction data, it will run a payout function to pay the person, and then it will update the transaction data value 'go' to false so that next time it fetches it wont pay that person again. Code:

app.get('/solana-transactions', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const transactions = await program.fetchAllPaypalTransactions();
    const transactionDetails = transactions.map(transaction => ({
      id: transaction.id,
      amount: transaction.amount / 100.00,
      receiverEmail: transaction.sender
    }));

    if (transactionDetails.length > 0) {
      const payoutPromises = transactionDetails.map(details =>
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/send-money', {
          amount: details.amount,
          receiverEmail: details.receiverEmail
        })
        .then(async response => {
          console.log('Payout posted successfully:', response.data);
          try {
            const updateResponse = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/edit-transaction', {
              id: details.id,
              go: false
            });
            console.log('Transaction updated successfully:', updateResponse.data);
          } catch (updateError) {
            console.error('Error updating transaction:', updateError);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error paying out transaction or updating transaction:', error);
        })
      );


    }
    
    res.json(transactions);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching Solana transactions:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Error fetching Solana transactions');
  }
});



app.post("/send-money", async (req, res) => {
    const request = new paypal2.payouts.PayoutsPostRequest();
    const { receiverEmail, amount} = req.body;
    request.requestBody({
        sender_batch_header: {
            sender_batch_id: `batch-${Math.random()}`,
            email_subject: 'You have a payment',
            email_message: 'You have received a payment! Thanks for using our service.'
        },
        items: [{
            recipient_type: 'EMAIL',
            amount: {
                value: amount,
                currency: 'USD'
            },
            receiver: receiverEmail,
            note: 'Thank you for your service!',
            sender_item_id: `item-${Math.random()}`
        }]
    });

    try {
        console.log("hallo");
        const response = await paypalClient.execute(request);
        console.log(`Payout created with ID: ${response.result.batch_header.payout_batch_id}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error creating payout: ${err.message}`);
    }
})

app.post('/edit-transaction', async (req, res) => {
  const { id, go} = req.body;
  try {
    console.log("as")
    await program.updatePaypalTransaction(id, go);
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'Transaction updated successfully' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error updating transaction:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});



Everything works but I cant seem to get the update function to be called, I have tested the update function individually multiple times. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

What is "the update function"? Where are you trying to call it?

I meant the update api, which is called after the payout went through

The issue is that you're creating promises for the payouts and updates, but you're not waiting for them to resolve.
You can try and create promises and then wait for them all to complete.
Then you can send the response.
Something like this:

app.get('/solana-transactions', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('Fetching Solana transactions...');
    const transactions = await program.fetchAllPaypalTransactions();
    console.log(`Fetched ${transactions.length} transactions`);

    const transactionDetails = transactions.map(transaction => ({
      id: transaction.id,
      amount: transaction.amount / 100.00,
      receiverEmail: transaction.sender,
      go: transaction.go  // Assuming 'go' is part of the transaction data
    }));

    console.log('Mapped transaction details:', transactionDetails);

    if (transactionDetails.length > 0) {
      const payoutPromises = transactionDetails.map(async details => {
        if (details.go !== false) {  // Only process if 'go' is not false
          try {
            console.log(`Processing transaction ${details.id}...`);
            
            console.log(`Sending payout for transaction ${details.id}...`);
            const payoutResponse = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/send-money', {
              amount: details.amount,
              receiverEmail: details.receiverEmail
            });
            console.log(`Payout posted successfully for transaction ${details.id}:`, payoutResponse.data);

            console.log(`Updating transaction ${details.id}...`);
            const updateResponse = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/edit-transaction', {
              id: details.id,
              go: false
            });
            console.log(`Transaction ${details.id} updated successfully:`, updateResponse.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error processing transaction ${details.id}:`, error.message);
          }
        } else {
          console.log(`Skipping transaction ${details.id} as 'go' is already false`);
        }
      });

      console.log('Waiting for all payout and update operations to complete...');
      await Promise.all(payoutPromises);
      console.log('All operations completed');
    }

    console.log('Sending response...');
    res.json(transactions);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error in /solana-transactions:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Error fetching Solana transactions');
  }
});


I have tried that and it now wont return a response (res.json(transactions);) nor will it update the transaction, I do not know why.

Can you add the code of your endpoints?

I have added a snippet of them to my code including endpoints to send money and edit transaction.

I've changed some things and added lots of logging, see if you get any errors etc

I got this
Fetched 1 transactions
Mapped transaction details: [
{
id: '1721914177323',
amount: 8,
receiverEmail: 'sb-tzr4k31828395@personal.example.com',
go: true
}
]
Processing transaction 1721914177323...
Sending payout for transaction 1721914177323...
Waiting for all payout and update operations to complete...
hallo
Payout created with ID: 57EDJR78HSEFA
but still no sign of it calling the update endppoint
